# How to execute a python cgi-script under Linux

Tags: python, linux, cgi

I have a python cgi script which executed fine on a Windows machine simply by starting CGIHTTPServer in the console, opening the html page to pass the data to the script and submitting the data.
I now need to do this under Linux but this is proving more difficult.  Some web searching has given this script to start the server (I've put in 8000 as the original 80 didn't work)

```
 import os  
 import BaseHTTPServer, CGIHTTPServer  
 serverAddr = ("", 8000)  
 os.chdir("/home/apannife/www")  
 serv = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer( \  
     serverAddr, CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)  
 serv.serve_forever()
```

the html.

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>

Test

</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<B>  Filename </B>

<FORM METHOD=post ACTION="cgi-bin/docking_cgi.py" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">

<INPUT Type="file" NAME="upfile" SIZE=45><BR>

<P><INPUT TYPE=submit></FORM>



</BODY></HTML>
```

and the first part of the cgi.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi

from cgi import FieldStorage


reshtml = '''Content-Type: text/html\n

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>

DEMO

</TITLE></HEAD>

<BODY><H3> OUTPUT SENT TO %s %s </H3>

</BODY></HTML>'''
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

upfile = form['upfile']
```

However submitting the data just returns the text of the cgi script and doesn't run it.  I've chmod-ded 775 everything in sight and it looks like the server is not automagically understanding that I want it to execute the script.  How do I make it do so?
thanks.

Comment: try chmod 755 on cgi-bin and everything else; on my server, group-write perm on the directory disallows execution.

Comment: that one is set to drwxr-xr-x so should be able to work

Answer (score 0):

The server only executes scripts under the directories `/cgi-bin` and `/htbin` relative to the server root.  In contrast to Windows, these names are case-sensitive on Linux.

Comment: I've got the html file in /home/apannife/www as that is where the os.chdir sets the default before starting the server.  I've made a cgi-bin directory underneath with the python script in it.  This is a first effort at a linux server so I could be doing something really naive.  I'm simply opening the html file in firefox and expecting it to work at the moment.

Comment: So 'www' is a symbolic link to 'public_html'; and the path to the python code is /home/apannife/public_html/cgi-bin/the-python-code, right? And the python file has the executable bit set, like 0755. If so then the permissions seem good.

Comment: No, www is a normal directory with cgi-bin a subdirectory of www.  And all the files and directories containing them are set to 755 (don't know what the leading "0" is of 0755).

Comment: @Alan: I tried your code on my machine and it works fine.  I suggest debugging your problem: 1. Copy `CGIHTTPServer.py` to the same directory as your server script. 2. Add some debug output to the `CGIHTTPRequestHandler.is_cgi()` 3. Run your server, access your CGI script and watch the debug output.

Comment: OK, I'll try that.  Currently, I have serve.py in the www directory and running that from the command line in a terminal as python server.py.  Then I'm opening the html file in firefox just by "File-> open file", entering the data and expecting it to run.  In the html code, I had to take the leading "/" off the ACTION command that I used in Windows to make it see the file in cgi-bin and wondering if this is causing problems.

Comment: @Alan -- Sorry I was away for a while. You say: "No, www is a normal directory with cgi-bin a subdirectory of www." OK, I'm still not quite sure ***but*** if it's not exactly like these following words, it won't work: the directory path to your html **must** be: /home/alan/public_html/ . And the path to your python cgi **must** be: /home/alan/public_html/cgi-bin/ . Often, "www" is a symbolic link to "public_html," which is just fine; but if it's a real subdirectory all by itself, on the same level as public_html, you are sol. That's the way it works; there's no getting around it.

Comment: @Alan - You say: "don't know what the leading "0" is of 0755." The leading 0 means that 755 is an octal representation of the number; ***everybody*** knows that -- what'sa matta' widjou? :-)